# How to load an XML file and get values from the nodes - VC++

Tags: xml, visual-c++

I'm new to VC++ and i want to load an XML file and read the values from the nodes using VC++. Any guidance?

Thank you

NLV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use one of the XML parsers libraries. In our projects we use [Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/). There are also solutions from Microsoft [MSXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759192(VS.85).aspx) or [XmlLite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163436.aspx).